# Unable load a CSV file as dataframe in spark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to load a CSV file in the data frame and my objective is to display the first row as the column name of the CSV file. but while using the below code, I am getting the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterNot(TraversableLike.scala:278)
```

**Code:**

```
def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {
 val spark : SparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("SparkSessioncsvExample")
      .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
      .getOrCreate()
   val df = spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true") //reading the headers
      .load("D:/Scala/C2ImportCalEventSample.csv")}
```

But I'm able to load the file with the code:

```
val df = spark.sparkContext
        .textFile("D:/Scala/C2ImportCalEventSample1.csv")
        //.flatMap(header='true')
        .map(line => line.split(","))
        // .map(line => line.map()
        .toDF()
```

but in the second code file is getting successfully loaded but the first row is not getting as column_name of the data frame.

```
spark version is: spark-2.3.2  
scala 2.11.3  
jdk1.8.0_20
sbt-1.2.7
```

Thanks any anyone who can help me on this.

Comment: your second method is actually loading the text file.. so you wont get the column names.. could you please paste the sample csv in the question

Comment: do u have scala 2.10 also on your classpath?

Comment: How do you execute the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.lang.AbstractMethodError almost always means that you have different libraries on the classpath than at compilation time.  In this case I would check to make sure you have the correct version of Scala (and only have one version of scala) on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks , Harjeet kumar, my env variable is pointing scala 2.12.8 and my sbt file it is 2.11.3,. I have change my env varibale to 2.11.8 version also in sbt file it is 2.11.8 version. and  it s working file. Thanks for help.